# Code Migration in MVC having MySql as Database

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I have enabled Migration for my project.

I also performed "**add-migration mylabel**".

But when I perform "Update-Database", the following error is displayed.

**Type is not resolved for member 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException,MySql.Data, Version=6.9.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d'.**

I searched for solution and found a solution to install MySQL Connector, but my installation fails halfway.

Answer (score 1):

Your runtime part should be like that in web config file

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="6.7.4.0" newVersion="6.9.9.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data.Entity" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="6.7.4.0" newVersion="6.9.9.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Web" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="6.7.4.0" newVersion="6.9.9.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>

      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

> And becareful for the password of your database in  connection string. **Default mode is empty** in most valid databases.